# How do you use pygame on a python 3.6.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, jupyter-notebook

I use a windows 7, and I use Jupyter notebook. I have recently downloaded pygame, but when I try to import pygame, it shows me this:

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import pygame

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

can someone teach me how to use it properly?

Comment: What steps did you take to install pygame after downloading it?

Comment: @Zack Tarr Umm . . . nothing. Since there was a bunch of files on my computer I thought I didn't need to do anything after that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this from a command prompt:

```
pip install pygame
```

This should download and install pygame to a location that Python can find and use it.

Then you can import pygame in Jupyter notebook. I tested this on Windows 8.

Comment: I tried it in the Python3.6 32 bit thingy but it said there is a syntax error. Can you clarify which command promp to use? P.S. I use a Windows 7

Comment: Any command console should run the pip command if python is on the windows path. So maybe python is not on your windows path. The pip command should be under e.g. c:/Python36/Scripts/pip.exe